# Accessing Bigquery from app engine. Example is out of date

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I am trying to access Bigquery from Appengine but the code example from https://developers.google.com/bigquery/authorization#service-accounts-appengine
does not compile since JsonHttpRequestInitializer is deprecated and not in the current libraries. Is there an update to date example that shows how to connect from Appengine from Bigquery? More specifically I am using Maven and trying to connect a Backend service to Bigquery.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be updated since it does not reference JsonHttpRequestInitialize anymore.